# my android app crashes for recording video?

Tags: android

im using the following code for recording video and playing using videoView.

```
static final int VIDEO_CAPTURE = 101;
    File mediaFile;
    VideoView videoView;

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Uri videoUri = Uri.fromFile(mediaFile);
        videoView.setVideoURI(videoUri);
        videoView.requestFocus();
        videoView.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_rec);
        videoView=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        mediaFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/myvideo.mp4");
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        Uri videoUri = Uri.fromFile(mediaFile);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, videoUri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, VIDEO_CAPTURE);
    }
```

but when ever i start activity camera opens but when i start recording my app crashes. what is the problem?

Comment: You should include the stacktrace from the crash.

Comment: hey bro.. now the problem is solved. now i can hear the sound on videoview but video stuck after 2 or 3 seconds.